# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reading 9 characters, but works with less than 9

Tags: objective-c, c, exc-bad-access

I'm developing a console app in Objective-C.  I've got it working, but when manually testing edge cases, I found a strange behavior that I can't explain.

Basically, I've set up scanf() in a loop, and when the user types invalid info, it prints an "invalid option" message.  Then, if the input is less than 9 characters long, it goes through the loop again as intended.  But, if the input is 9 characters or longer, it gives a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on a certain line.
(This error doesn't happen if I comment out said line.)
I can't figure out any reason why 8 vs 9 characters being read would cause this error.  Any ideas?

Below are the two methods that I figure are relevant, with a comment on the line throwing the error.  If you think other referenced code may be causing this, let me know and I'll add that code.

```
-(void)startMenu {
    printf("\nGAME OPTIONS\n| WinningScore = %d (w) | Name = %s (n) | Back (b) |\n",
           _options.winningScore, [_options.name UTF8String]);
}

-(void)start {
    char selectedOption;
    char w = 'w';
    char n = 'n';
    char b = 'b';
    while(YES) {
        [self startMenu]; // This line gets the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
        // if the user puts in 9 or more characters.
        // If it is commented out, then no error is thrown.

        scanf("%s", &selectedOption);
        if(selectedOption == w) {
            [self setWinningScore];
        } else if(selectedOption == n) {
            [self setName];
        } else if(selectedOption == b) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("'%s' is not a valid option.\n", &selectedOption);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `char selectedOption`

Answer (score 2):

It this was C (and the post is tagged C) I'd suggest:

```
char selectedOption;
....
scanf(" %c", &selectedOption);
...
printf("'%c' is not a valid option.\n", selectedOption);
```

---

The failure showing up after a 9 charterer input is serendipity.  `scanf("%s", &selectedOption);` is certainly wrong for reading a single character.  Any input starts causing problems.  Use the matching format specifier and variable.

---

[Edit]
A C-like solution.
If more than 1 `char` is desire for input, use the idea put forth by @Devolus.  Example:

```
char selectedOption[10];
if (fgets(selectedOption, sizeof selectedOption, stdin) == NULL) 
  Handle_EOForIOerror();
// Get rid of potential trailing \n if desired.
size_t len = strlen(selectedOption);
if (len > 0 && selectedOption[len-1] == '\n') selectedOption[--len] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) instead of `scanf` here, as you can limit the number of characters in the buffer.

scanf is potentially unsafe because the buffer can be exceeded.